# Pressure and Leak Testing of Rockets

Tags: space-shuttle, spacecraft, qualification-testing

For any pressure vessel, hydrostatic/pneumatic pressure testing and helium leak testing  are carried out as per UG-99/UG-100 and ASME, Section V, Article 10, respectively. For a rocket, what are the test conditions for pressure and leak testing and how temperature and speed are taken into account  during testing for qualifying the integrity of spacecraft/space shuttle?

Comment: Which of the dozens of pressure vessels on the shuttle are you interested in?

Comment: @Organic Marble : Command module, lunar module, fuel tank and the primary containment while taking off. Thank you.